# how to add second module in intellj idea and push it to git repo

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

trying to add second module in intellj idea and push it to git repo,
but cannot figure out how do it...

creating new module in existing project by:
file-> new-> module...
[image]

then press ctrl+K
[image]

after
[image]

i got messages - Push successful ToDo: Everything is up-to-date and 9 files committed: init
but in my github repo nothing changed, what im doing wrong?

Comment: On your screenshot you can see that there are two repositories - ToDo and todo_jdbc.
todo_jdbc has no remote defined. You need to add a remote for this repository and then push - this way your second module would appear on GitHub, in a separate repository.
Would you like to add your module to ToDo repository? In this case you should have .git in a parent repository (it must be parent for ToDo and todo_jdbc)

Comment: @Ruslan Kuleshov i figure out that make module form maven, not spring.io

Answer (score 0):

do not create with sping.io
create with    maven arch
main thing - parent
[image]